# The system cannot find the path specified in Eclipse(Web project)

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to get a pdf file in my project,the compiler is always saying "java.io.FileNotFoundException: \WEB-INF\Blank_A4.pdf(The system cannot find the path specified)":

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZAsk.png)

And my code is:

[Code snipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6fvt.png)

And my project structure is:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZWK8.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We're happy to help, but you need to make it easy for us. Please actually include your code, not an image. I find it odd that the compiler is looking for a PDF, however. Why would the compiler need a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Is this error actually a run-time error? I don't see why you would get an error when the project is built.

Assuming a run-time error, common problems could be:

- The code starts with a "\" instead of a relative path
- The pdf is not in the output project (is the pdf in the created war file?)
- The pdf would be a resource, and you would have to read it as a resource

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.File` and every File-related class in that package use locations on disk. "\WEB-INF\Blank_A4.pdf" is not a location on disk. Without knowing the context of the code you showed--what variables it has to work with--there's not much to suggest other than looking at the methods in the `javax.servlet.ServletContext` interface for how to open input streams if it's available to you at runtime.